# What technology should I use for inter-process events/notifications?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, message-queue, nservicebus

In our application, we plan to have a central data storage which may be accessed by multiple applications through WCF services. However, if data is changed and saved in one application, all other applications should be notified of this change because otherwise the applications would be out-of-sync. This notification would only contain the type of data which has been changed and its unique ID. Afterwards, the application would ask the database for the updated data. So, it seems to be a pretty simple scenario.

My question is: **Which technology should we use for those notifications?**

I have found the following technologies, but I am unsure which of them fits best for our scenario:

- Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ)
- NServiceBus
- Callback Channels

Comment: how often are those db updates? MQs perform well when you have lots of traffic (I believe that's what they're made for-twitter uses Rabbit MQ)

Comment: DB updates are not very often. Typically, only one or two PCs (one user each) will have access to the database (no web access, only local network). Updates are typically done by the user manually.

Comment: It sounds like any of those will meet your requirements. If you have no more requirements, we have no way of deciding between them. What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: What is the storage mechanism for the distributed applications?  Also, what is the backend database vendor?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 real time messaging products/technologies that I use and have found very helpful:

- [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)
- FrozenMountian's [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/)

  - This is kind of pricey - but the free version will allow you up to 10 connections.
  - The time it saves is worth every penny.

I guess this could be considered overkill for what you need - but they are very useful tools.

Answer (score 2):

For MS SQL Server, you might take a look at [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). Quote:

*"SqlDependency is ideal for caching scenarios, where your ASP.NET application or middle-tier service needs to keep certain information cached in memory. SqlDependency allows you to receive notifications when the original data in the database changes so that the cache can be refreshed."*

This would allow you to listen to the changes directly at the database level, without the need for any special synchronization between the application instances. As an added bonus, this would work even when database is changed by something other than your application.